# I changed JAVA_HOME in .bash_profiles how do i change the java version it uses

Tags: java, java-home

I have 3 versions of java installed: `adoptopenjdk-8.jdk`, `jdk-12.0.2.jdk`and `jdk1.0.0_221.jdk`

when I set the `JAVA_HOME` variable to `JAVA_HOME="/usr/libexec/java_home"`
then when I go to terminal type `$JAVA_HOME`, it gives the `jdk-12.0.0.jdk`version.
 How would I change it so it gives the `adoptopenjdk-8.jdk` version?

I tried to set it to:
`export JAVA_HOME="/Library⁩/Java⁩/JavaVirtualMachines⁩/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk⁩/⁨Contents⁩/Home"`

`export PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH"`

Expected to give `adoptopenjdk-8.jdk` java version.
But not sure how to change it to `adoptopenjdk-8.jdk` version rather than `jdk-12.0.0.jdk`

Comment: change the symlink of `/etc/java` to your java version

Comment: how? do I do that?

Comment: For managing JDK versions (and not only) on Unix-like platforms I would recommend [SDKMAN!](https://sdkman.io/)

Comment: ok will see but not sure if that can change the java_home

Comment: JAVA_HOME is just an environment variable that some applications use. If you put the java bin on your path, then when you type java you should get the first version that appears first in your PATH value. Why do you say it is telling you jdk 12 then?

Comment: It gives this when I type $JAVA_HOME if I set it to JAVA_HOME="/usr/libexec/java_home" in the bash_profiles.
------
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-12.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home

Comment: What do you want to do? Either you can set JAVA_HOME to point to a specific version and then your program and any other that uses JAVA_HOME will use that version or you can change what /usr/libexec/java_home points to but then you will change the version for the whole computer so to speak.

Comment: @TBM-Codes With this `sudo ln -s <location to your java directory>/bin/java /usr/bin/java`